# Single CodeIgniter-4 working with domain and subdomain

Tags: api, .htaccess, routes, subdomain, codeigniter-4

I have set a single CodeIgniter4 to work on [www.example.com/controller/method](http://www.example.com/controller/method), but I also need certain groups of controllers (like api) to work only from api.example.com/controller/method
May I ask you guys for a best practice approach to achieve this ?

Comment: Could you please confirm if you want to redirect from url `www.example.com/controller/method` TO `api.example.com/controller/method` since you have added htaccess tag here.

Comment: Sure, htaccess is a way to do it, but I'm thinking if it's not better/correct  to use CI native routing and have no redirection...

Comment: The way I have done is, I have segregated the controllers and routes at the base of the Project. For example , the main routes are in the app/Routes folder (which is by default). And to differentiate the subdomains folder, they are definited in Subdomain/app/Routes and their respective logics are in app/Controllers and Subdomain/app/Controllers.

Comment: @DhavalChheda Indeed it seems the right way to do it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the right way to do it was indicated by @DhavalChheda

The way I have done is, I have segregated the controllers and routes at the base of the Project. For example , the main routes are in the app/Routes folder (which is by default). And to differentiate the subdomains folder, they are definited in Subdomain/app/Routes and their respective logics are in app/Controllers and Subdomain/app/Controllers.